# Pygame Pacman ghost, random change direction

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

I am creating a pacman game, so far everything works aside from the ghosts, when a ghost collides against a wall the class bellow is called. However as you can see `self.a` returns a str, but I need it to be applied to my ghost sprites, Ghost1,Ghost2, etc. So it calls, Ghost1.a and the ghost moves accordingly.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
class Ghost_move(object):
    def __init__(self,g_speed):
        super(Ghost_move, self).__init__()
        self.left=".rect.x-=g_speed"
        self.right=".rect.x+=g_speed"
        self.up=".rect.y-=g_speed"
        self.down=".rect.y+=g_speed"
        self.direction=self.left,self.right,self.up,self.down
        self.a=random.choice(self.direction)
```

Comment: Why did you even need super() ?

Comment: i dont, sublime text adds it automatically when creating a new class, I just forgot to delete it

Comment: This is a terrible idea to save literals in a string, just use multiple if statements or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As abccd already pointed out, it is a bad idea to put source code, that you want to be executed into strings. The solution that is nearest to yours is defining functions for `left`, `right`, `up`, `down`. Then you can store those functions in directions and execute a randomly chosen one:

```
class Ghost_move(object):
    def __init__(self,g_speed):
        super(Ghost_move, self).__init__()
        self.g_speed = g_speed
        self.directions = self.left, self.right, self.up, self.down
        self.a = random.choice(self.directions)
    def left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.g_speed
    def right(self):
        self.rect.x += self.g_speed
    def up(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.g_speed
    def down(self):
        self.rect.y += self.g_speed
```

Now `self.a` is a function that you can call. For example `ghost1.a()` would move `ghost1` randomly in one of the four directions. But be careful, because a is just set once and therefore `ghost1.a()` always moves this ghost in the same direction and does not choose a random direction everytime you call it.

---

A different approach is to do it with vectors:

```
class Ghost_move(object):
    def __init__(self,g_speed):
        super(Ghost_move, self).__init__()
        self.left = (-g_speed, 0)
        self.right = (g_speed, 0)
        self.up = (0, -g_speed)
        self.down = (0, g_speed)
        self.directions = self.left, self.right, self.up, self.down
        self.random_dir = random.choice(self.directions)
    def a():
        self.rect.x += self.random_dir[0]
        self.rect.y += self.random_dir[1]
```

The usage is the same as before, you would just call `a()` on a ghost.